# How to I make sure my N1QL Query considers recent changes?

Tags: java, scala, caching, couchbase, sql++

My situation is that, given 3 following methods (I used couchbase-java-client 2.2 in Scala. And Version of Couchbase server is 4.1):

```
def findAll() = {
    bucket.query(N1qlQuery.simple(select("*").from(i(DatabaseBucket.USER))))
      .allRows().toList
  }

  def findById(id: UUID) = {
    Option(bucket.get(id.toString, classOf[RawJsonDocument])).map(i => read[User](i.content()))
  }

  def upsert(i: User) = {
    bucket.async().upsert(RawJsonDocument.create(i.id.toString, write(i)))
  }
```

Basically, they are insert, find one by id and findAll. I did an experiment where :

- I insert a `User`, then find one by `findById` right after that, I got a user that I have inserted correctly.
- I insert and then I use `findAll` right after that, it returns empty.
- I insert, put 3 seconds delay and then I use `findAll`, I can find the one that I have inserted.

By that, I suspected that N1qlQuery only search over cached layer rather than "persist" layer. So, how can I force to let it search on "persist" layer?

Comment: Might be good to rephrase the title of this, as you're stating it as a fact rather than a question and the mechanics are different.  Suggested: "How to I make sure my N1QL Query considers recent changes?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Couchbase 4.0 with N1QL, there are different [consistency levels](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/architecture/querying-data-with-n1ql.html) you can specify when querying which correspond to different cost for updates/changes to propagate through index recalculation.  These aren't tied to whether or not data is persisted, but rather it's an option when you issue the query.  The default is "not bounded" and to make sure that your upsert request is taken into consideration, you'll want to issue this query as "request plus".

To get the effect you're looking for, you'll want to add N1qlPararms on your creation of the N1qlQuery by using [another form of the simple() method](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.3/com/couchbase/client/java/query/N1qlQuery.html#simple-com.couchbase.client.java.query.Statement-com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlParams-).  Add a N1qlParams with [ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.3/com/couchbase/client/java/query/consistency/ScanConsistency.html). You can read more about this in [Couchbase's Developer Guide](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/developer-guide/query-consistency.html).  There's a [Java API example of this](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/couchbase/devguide/QueryConsistency.java).  With that change, you won't need to have a sleep() in there, the system will automatically service the query request once the index recalculation has gotten to your specified level.

Depending on how you're using this elsewhere in your application, there are times you may want either consistency level.

Answer (score 2):

You need stronger scan consistency. Add a N1qlParam to the query, using `consistency(ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)`